Filter data in the mobile application Creatio (Freedom UI)
Please help me set up the filter 'CreatedBy=Current user'.
I found an example of a filter, but I'm having trouble adapting it to my needs and integrating it into the page code.
"viewModelConfig": {
"attributes": {
    "Items": {
        "modelConfig": {
            "path": "PDS",
            "filterAttributes": [
                {"name": "CustomFilter"}
            ]
        }
    },
    "CustomFilter": {
        "value": {
            "items": {
                "63871ecc-40a1-4f00-a7e5-9c5099a76ea4": {
                    "filterType": 4,
                    "comparisonType": 3,
                    "isEnabled": true,
                    "trimDateTimeParameterToDate": false,
                    "leftExpression": {"expressionType": 0, "columnPath": "Owner"},
                    "isAggregative": false,
                    "key": "63871ecc-40a1-4f00-a7e5-9c5099a76ea4",
                    "dataValueType": 10,
                    "leftExpressionCaption": "Owner",
                    "referenceSchemaName": "Contact",
                    "rightExpressions": [
                        {
                            "expressionType": 2,
                            "parameter": {"dataValueType": 10, "value": "410006e1-ca4e-4502-a9ec-e54d922d2c00"}
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "logicalOperation": 0,
            "isEnabled": true,
            "filterType": 6,
            "rootSchemaName": "Opportunity"
        }
    }
}

}
Perhaps there are examples of using filters in the Creatio mobile application
